# Растягивающийся GridPanel

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Здравствуйте! 
У меня есть `GridPanel` 3x1, требуется сделать так чтобы боковые столбцы были фиксированного размера, а центральное которое вмещает в себе `ScrollPanel` должно подстраиваться под размер окна приложения. С боковыми как-то удалось решить задачу, а вот с центральной как не изменяю настройки в Scene Builder, получается так что центральный столбец увеличивается на 100% содержимого и правая ячейка уходит за пределы окна приложения.

На всякий случай, внизу прикрепил код cгенерированный Scene Builder.

Правая ячейка ушла за пределы окна
[image: Правая ячейка ушла за пределы окна]

Увеличил окно, появилась правая ячейка и `ScrollPane` не растянулся на всю ширину центральной ячейки
[image: Увеличил окно, появилась правая ячейка, а <code>ScrollPane</code> не растянулся на всю ширину центральной ячейки]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="-Infinity" />
        <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="-Infinity" />
        <ColumnConstraints minWidth="-Infinity" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="760.0" prefWidth="0.0" spacing="3.0">
         <children>
             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/folder_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/length_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/center_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/pellets_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/reset_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/zoomPlus_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/actualSize_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/zoomMinus_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/save_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/screenshoot_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>

             <Button mnemonicParsing="false">
                 <graphic>
                     <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                             <Image url="@../image/settings_sm.png" />
                         </image>
                     </ImageView>
                 </graphic>
             </Button>
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
         </padding>
        </VBox>
        <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.valignment="TOP" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <content>
            <Pane>
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="1000.0" fitWidth="1000.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../image/2.jpg" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </content>
        </ScrollPane>
        <TabPane tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="Мишень">
                    <content>
                        <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="3.0">
                            <children>
                                <FlowPane>
                                    <children>
                                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Название: " />
                                        <TextField>
                                            <FlowPane.margin>
                                                <Insets top="3.0" />
                                            </FlowPane.margin>
                                        </TextField>
                                    </children>
                                </FlowPane>
                                <DatePicker />
                                <HBox spacing="3.0" />
                                <HBox layoutX="13.0" layoutY="69.0" spacing="3.0" />
                                <GridPane hgap="3.0">
                                    <columnConstraints>
                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                    </columnConstraints>
                                    <rowConstraints>
                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                    </rowConstraints>
                                    <children>
                                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Пуля: " GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                        <ChoiceBox prefWidth="100.0" value="Метры" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                                            <items>
                                                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                    <String fx:value="Метры" />
                                                    <String fx:value="Ярды" />
                                                </FXCollections>
                                            </items>
                                        </ChoiceBox>
                                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Дистанция: " />
                                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                        <ChoiceBox prefWidth="100.0" value="мм" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                            <items>
                                                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                    <String fx:value="мм" />
                                                    <String fx:value="дюймы" />
                                                </FXCollections>
                                            </items>
                                        </ChoiceBox>
                                    </children>
                                </GridPane>
                                <TextArea wrapText="true">
                                    <VBox.margin>
                                        <Insets right="3.0" />
                                    </VBox.margin></TextArea>
                            </children>
                            <padding>
                                <Insets left="3.0" />
                            </padding>
                        </VBox>
                    </content></Tab>
                <Tab text="Статистика">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Примечания">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: можно вместо грида использовать AnchorPane, и в них указать привязки к бокам всего окна